# Parent and SubCategory Drop Down Menu

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I'm using Smarty, PHP and MySQL.

This should be very easy for someone that understands how to do this. I'm a noob and have no idea.

Trying to get a horizontal nav bar with parent and subcategories in the drop down.

The current code only displays the parent and I need the subcategories to display under.

I don't think I have any SQL to get the subcats and don't really know how to write it, so maybe someone can help.

```
TABLE >>> CATEGORY

    category_id  name      parent_id
    1            Parent    0
    2            Parent    0
    2            Parent    0
    3            Child     1
    4            Child     2
    5            Child     2
    6            Child     3
    7            Child     3
```

Current Function to get Categories

```
 // list of all categories
function getCategoriesList($include_subcats = false) {

 $where = '';

 if ($include_subcats != false) {
   $where = ' where parent_id = 0 ';
 }
$list =
 getSqlResult(
   "select * from category $where ORDER BY parent_id ASC",
   SQL_RESULT_ALL);

 return $list;
}
```

Template Code to Display the Menu

```
{foreach name=CategoriesList from=$CategoriesList item=i}
<li class="dropdown "><a href="/{$i.category_filename}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{$i.category_name}<b class="caret"></b></a
</li>{/foreach}
```

Comment: there is a few way to do it. i answered the question  hope you will understand the way

Comment: You appear to have duplicate rows

Answer (score 0):

you can do it to return the function

firstly we will write parents because their catid is 0

```
              function categori($upcatid=0, $satir=0, $bosluk=""){
            // $upcatid  is 0 for began that means is we will see the all parent
                $data["result"]= $categori->kategori($upcatid);// i got my all cats from db
                foreach ($data["result"] as $key => $kategorim) {
        // lets look at the cats parent categories parent_id are 0 if categori parent is not 0 it main the categori have parent! so we are going to return the function and call the parent firstly

                if(!isset($disabled))
                     $disabled='';
                echo '<option value="'.$kategorim["id"].'" '.$disabled.' >'.str_repeat("->>", $satir).">$bosluk ".$kategorim["catname"].'</option>';
   categori($kategorim["id"], $satir+1); // now get the categori id and retun the function  
    //call the all childs of the cat.

                }
            }
```

i wrote all categories in select options

```
if($upcatid==0)
echo ' <li class="dropdown">
              <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">'.$kategorim["catname"].' <b class="caret"></b></a>

';
elseif($upcatid!==0){
echo '  <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a href="#">'.$kategorim["catname"].'</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">'.categori($kategorim["id"], $satir+1).'</a></li>

                  </ul>
                </li>';


echo '</li>';
```

all you need to modify your project

Comment: Hi Ahmet. Thanks for your answer. Not sure how to make this work within my Smarty templates. I pasted it in, but it does not work.

Comment: It does not work because you need to modify this code for your project. If you understooth to make tree cat the other part is easy just look at bootstrap multi dropdown example. You will modify for your projede

Comment: Not sure how to modify. I need a complete solution in order to understand how to make this work with a Smarty template. Not supposed to use PHP like this in the Smarty template.

Comment: If anyone is searching for this solution.... Here is it . http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=25510